# Flutter - How 2 Give different width to different container enclosed in a single column?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to develop a clone of an App idea from dribble, which can be found [here](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/4208985/screenshots/15797352/media/cbeda99751314125e53dd9aab55b0914.png?compress=1&resize=1600x1200).

Can you please tell me is the code I'm trying to write is correct or not??
As I've tried to wrap a Column with two text Widgets Enclosed in Container ( separate ) and when I'm trying to change the width of one container It changes the margin of the other also.

My Code is :-

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
              child: const Text(
                'Find Intrested Events to Join',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  wordSpacing: 2,
                ),
              ),
              width: 200,
            ),
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20),
              width: 220,
              child: Text(
                'We share all events like Charity, workshop, Blood drive, etc.',
                style: TextStyle(wordSpacing: 2, height: 1.4),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Can you tell me How to achieve that stage that I can change the Containers' width without affecting the margin of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better to use `Stack` for this case while it contains background image, Also learn more about `Stack`, `Align`, `Positioned` and `LayoutBuilder` from [flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets)

Play with this widget ,

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(.4),
              ), //background image
              Positioned(
                left: 20,
                top: 30,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: constraints.maxWidth * .5, // 50% of width
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Find Intrested Events to Join',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                          wordSpacing: 2,
                        ),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ), //spaces between text
                      Text(
                        'We share all events like Charity, workshop, Blood drive, etc.',
                        style: TextStyle(wordSpacing: 2, height: 1.4),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                // also Postisioned can be use
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text("hereh"),
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Button"))
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll surly learn about them too as I've just completed a tutorial and started to develop on my own for the first time Thanks for the advise

BTW you are way too fast I didn't expected that you'll come up with my complete class for the app ( which is way much close to the one I chose )